# What to edit in React boiler plate to launch your app?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, firebase, deployment

Today I made a React app that works with an API to give a weather forecast from an input city. It works perfectly on a Node developement server (npm start) and I am ready to deploy it to Firebase to add to my portfolio, but I am really struggling to do so, because I don't think I understand how React works. (the issue is not firebase because I deployed a plain static website earlier without issue)

So after reading a lot of articles and watching videos, these are my steps to deploy my app:

1. npm run build
2. firebase init
3. firebase deploy, then follow steps till I get my url.

The  result is a blank page, because my HTML is still the boilerplate code that comes when you create a React app with Node, which basically just explains that you need to reference script. How I understand it, your 'public/index.html' should reference '/src/index.js' which then refers to 'app.js'. So when I realised that my index.html code doesn't reference the index.js file at all, I added it in a script tag (<.script type="module" src="/src/index.js">), but that didn't make any difference and my page is still blank.

Am I missing something simple, or do I misunderstand React completely? I feel like it might be going right over my head since I can't find any good explanation online

Comment: The period in my script tag was added intentionally

Comment: You need to deploy the build _outputs_, in `build/`. That will include an `index.html`, created from `public/index.html`, with the correct links injected into it. Read https://create-react-app.dev/docs/deployment/.